# Syntax error: Unexpected '/' error

Tags: php

I'm using fopen() but I get this error on execution.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '/' in /home/furtherpath.. on line 7
```

The line 7 is:

```
/home/a11*****/public_html/rishi/rishi_someone_php.php = fopen("rishi_someone_php.php","r");
```

I know I should place a file handler instead but that also doesn't seem to work and gives the same error.
Can't figure out why.

What I'm doing is creating a html page using php.:

```
$html="<html> \n <head> \n <title>".$fn."</title> \n </head> \n <body> \n <?php \n $file=fopen('".$full."','r'); \n while(!(feof($file))) \n { \n echo htmlspecialchars(fgets($file)).'<br/>'; \n } \n fclose($file); \n ?> \n </body> \n </html>";
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$somevar = fopen("rishi_someone_php.php","r");`?

Comment: I already mentioned the file handler gives the same thing...

Comment: You won't get a syntax error with the code I just provided. If it does emit an error, it's probably `Warning: fopen(rishi_someone_php.php): failed to open stream` or something. Edit in the correct error message please.

Comment: You're going to need to show the whole script.

Comment: Why do you have php tags in php tags?

Comment: No no... This is a string $html which is going to provide contents for a html page using fwrite()

Comment: Okay, what are you specifically doing with line 7, then?  It looks like you're trying to set the contents of a file to the file handle?  Either way, there's your problem.  That is invalid syntax, check what DaveChen did above; that's the correct way.. otherwise, well, you already know what happens with the parse error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a cleaned up version of your script. Try to understand it. I'e combined the string at each html element just to be clear. There is no reason for php tags within php tags. In your code at this line `$file=fopen('".$full."','r');`

You are trying to quote a variable of type string. That is not necessary with variables. PHP will know that it is a string, so don't do that. Only use quotes when a string literal is being passed into the function as an arguments.

```
$html = "<html>\n<head><title>". $fn."</title>\n</head><body>\n";

$fp = fopen($full, "r");
if ($fp) {
    while (($line = fgets($fp)) !== false) {
        $html .= htmlspecialchars($line, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        $html .= "<br />";
    }
} else {
    $html .= "No data";
    $html .=  "<br />";
} 

fclose($fp);

$html .= "</body>\n</html>\n";

echo $html;
```

Comment: This is unnecessarily complicated, and as it stands, not a good answer with no explanation.

Comment: It's the exact thing he has just cleared to understand.

Comment: Not quite, the user doesn't appear to have any good knowledge of php.  This wouldn't really help as it currently is(as of writing this comment), and is just giving the user code.  If I were you, I'd at least offer to explain why what they were doing is wrong.

Comment: Wait I understood... And found the bug too, I was putting quotes around the variable $full. Thank you all for your help.